# how to check JsonObject has null value(windows.data.json)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

### How can I check if any key from json object have null value

```
  JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();   

  string id = itemObject["id"].GetString() == null ? "" : itemObject["id"].GetString();

  this is my code but app crashes on it if null value for key "id"
```

Comment: Have you tried `itemObject["id"] == null`?

Comment: I have tried both way which you have mentioned but not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IJsonValue idValue = itemObject.GetNamedValue("id");

if ( idValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.Null)
{
    // is Null
}
else if (idValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.String)
{
    string id = idValue.GetString();
}
```

If you do this too much, consider adding [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198241.aspx).

To do the opposite use:

```
IJsonValue value = JsonValue.CreateNullValue();
```

Read [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/02/networking-api-improvements-in-windows-10/) more about null values.

Comment: my bad luck.. I have not refreshed the page, seen your answer after I resolved issue same way.

Answer (score 0):

if `itemObject["id"]` is null then the method `null.GetString()` doesn't exist and you'll get the error specified (null object never has any methods/fields/properties).

```
string id = itemObject["id"] == null ? (string)null : itemObject["id"].GetString(); // (string)null is an alternative to "", both are valid null representations for a string, but you should use whichever is your preference consistently to avoid errors further down the line
```

the above avoids calling `.GetString()` until you've asserted that the ID isn't null ([check here for more in-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)), if you're using C#6 you should be able to use the [new shorthand](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825488/New-Features-in-Csharp-Null-Conditional-Operator):

```
string id = itemObject["id"]?.GetString();
```

Comment: 1) It makes no sense to use the null conidional operator after ["id"], since JsonObject's indexer never returns null. Though it would throw KeyNotFoundException if there is no such property in your JSON.
2) (string)null is not a null representation for a string. Null is null, and "" is not null - it is a string of zero length.

Comment: 1) KeyNotFoundException is reason enough. 2) (string)null compiles.

Comment: Ok, so I can't press enter in a comment.. the exception you receive from (2) if you omit the (string) cast is to do with how C# unboxes variables. In a nutshell it's because null is typeless the compiler will throw a wobbly. - that is the technical term FYI

Comment: There is no boxing or unboxing, string is always a reference type, so it doesn't need to be boxed. There will be no exception thrown in (2), but rather a compilation error. Moreover, in C# 6.0 you don't need to cast a null in the ternary operator (?:), the compiler is smart enough to infer the resulting type automatically.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Comment: both sides of the null-coalescing operator must be of the same type so I think the OP would need to write code like this?
`string id = ( itemObject["id"] ?? Guid.Empty ).GetString();`

Comment: try string id = ( itemObject["id"].GetString() ?? " " );

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for the issue

string id = itemObject["id"].ValueType == JsonValueType.Null ? "" : itemObject["id"].GetString();